# How to filter a list with no strings elements

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, dataset

I have looked here, in several posts, but I can't solve it

here my list

```
lista = {-7.54, -4.49, -4.94, -5.87, -7.26, -7.38, -8.3, -7.79, -6.4, -9.58,-6.5, -9.47, -4.2, -4.15, -5.96, -7.47, -6.9, -5.65, -6.03, -7.61,-7., -7.26, -7.82, -8.86, -6.09, -10.4, -9.16, -8.42, -1.7,-7.05,-7.77, -8.63, -7.63, -9.56, -5., -7.01, -8.82, -8.08, -7.12, -8.,-8.42, -4.8, -7.89, -7.,-6.99, -6.85, -7.99, -6.2, -6.93, -4.06,-8.67, -7.53, -8.14, -6.11, -7.5, -6.31, -5.4, -8.67, -9.62,-7.1,-6.61, -7.39, NA, -7.19, -8.45, -6.14, NA, NA, NA, -8.11,-7.88, -6.96, -8.89, -6.92, -6.42, -4.91, -6.22}
```

I need to remove or filter from a list, ALL the elements "**NA**" 'cause I needed to calculate statistical data, the database is much bigger than this, it is just a sample.
**NA** isn't a STRING in my list (see the pic)

[image]

Any ideas? thanks advance.

Comment: `Cases[lista, Except[NA]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html), [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html), [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) and [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) as follows:

```
lista1 = Select[NumericQ] @ lista
```

> ```
> {-7.54, -4.49, -4.94, -5.87, -7.26, -7.38, -8.3, -7.79, -6.4, -9.58,
> -6.5, -9.47, -4.2, -4.15, -5.96, -7.47, -6.9, -5.65, -6.03, -7.61, 
> -7., -7.26, -7.82, -8.86, -6.09, -10.4, -9.16, -8.42, -1.7, -7.05, 
> -7.77, -8.63, -7.63, -9.56, -5., -7.01, -8.82, -8.08, -7.12, -8., 
> -8.42, -4.8, -7.89, -7., -6.99, -6.85, -7.99, -6.2, -6.93, -4.06, 
> -8.67, -7.53, -8.14, -6.11, -7.5, -6.31, -5.4, -8.67, -9.62, -7.1, 
> -6.61, -7.39, -7.19, -8.45, -6.14, -8.11, -7.88, -6.96, -8.89, -6.92, 
> -6.42, -4.91, -6.22}
> ```

```
lista2 = DeleteCases[NA] @ lista;

lista3 = Cases[_?NumericQ] @ lista;

lista4 = ReplaceAll[NA -> Nothing] @ lista;


lista1 == lista2 == lista3 == lista4
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: How would this be in this case? with NA elemets, I'm new to using math, btw thanks again..... 
                                                                                                                                    `lista = {{Pal_1, 130.067, 19.023, 13.7, 20.3, -1.01, -2.54, 0.6, 19.9, NA, 7.1, 2.37, 0.74, 2.9, 16.76, 0.15, 13.62, 12.36}, {NGC_1466, 286.7, -39.537, 39.4, 38.4, -2.15, -7.54, 2.8, 73.9, NA, 8.82, 2.48, 3.69, 14.3, 18.8, 0.07, 10.66, 10.23}}`

Comment: For list of lists as input, you can use `Select[NumericQ] /@ lista` or 
`Cases[_?NumericQ] /@ lista` or `DeleteCases[Except[_?NumericQ]] /@ lista`.

Comment: `lista = {{12.06,10.77} , {7.33,NA} , {6.34,4.21}}`                                                                           I need remove only `{7.33,NA} ` .. I just need this on my list  `lista = {{12.06,10.77} , {6.34,4.21}} `  @kglr, can you help?, this is a nightmare for me

Comment: try `DeleteCases[{_,NA}]@lista` or `Select[FreeQ[NA]]@lista`

Comment: thanks again amte